# C-x 5 0 quits emacs in full-screen mode on Mac High Sierra

Tags: osx

I am running MacOS High Sierra. When I create new frames using  `C-x 5 2` and try to close one of the frames using `C-x 5 0` running in full-screen mode, it kills Emacs entirely instead of deleting the frame I want to kill, and I get an "Emacs quit unexpectedly" message. `C-x 5 0` works normally if I don't have the frames in full-screen mode. Anyone know of a possible fix for this (other than not running Emacs in full screen)?

Comment: Try the Emacs 26 pre-release, it should be fixed there.